# Is the complexity of this covering problem known?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, graph-theory, co.combinatorics, optimization

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph. A vertex set $X\subseteq V$ is called *critical* if $X\neq\emptyset$ and no vertex in $V\setminus X$ is adjacent to exactly one vertex in $X$. The problem is to find a vertex set $S\subseteq V$ of minimum size such that $S\cap X\neq\emptyset$ for every critical set $X$.

The problem has the following rumour-spreading interpretation: Vertex $i$ spreads the rumour to its neighbour $j$ if and only if all other neighbours of $i$ are already informed. The question is then how many vertices do I have to inform initially to make sure that everybody is informed in the end.

Comment: This has a pretty simple solution, so perhaps the problem has more conditions than specified; ignoring the special case $X=V$ and if $G$ is connected, every vertex $v$ with degree $>1$ has a critical set $V\setminus\{v\}$ associated with it, so only neighbors of exclusively deg 1 vertices can be in $S$. If such a vertex exists, then $G$ is a star graph and its center (as a singleton) is the unique minimal $S$. If $G$ is not connected then look at each connected component.

Comment: For a star $K_{1,n}$ with $n\geqslant 2$ leaves, every set of two leaves is critical, and therefore the optimal solution is to take $n-1$ leaves.

Comment: Oh, I see my mistaken interpetation

Comment: Very interesting question, one minor quibble: you probably want to require your critical sets to be nonempty (otherwise there is no $S$).

Comment: A question: suppose that $E = \{ (1,3), (2,3), (3,4) \}$ is $X = \{ 1,2\}$ critical ?

Comment: @MarzioDeBiasi, didn't he answer that in the first comment? (the answer being ‘yes’) [and, btw, this why I tried to reject the first edit]

Comment: It is worth noting that the decision version of this problem is in $\Sigma_2^p$, but I don't see directly how it might be in NP

Comment: @JoeBebel: The decision problem "Is there a solution set $S$ of size at most $K$?" is in NP. You can check if a set $S$ is a solution by the following algorithm. While there is a vertex $v\in S$ which has exactly on neighbour $w$ outside $S$, add $w$ to $S$. If $S$ contains eventually all vertices then your initial set was a solution, otherwise you get stuck, and the complement of the final set is a critical set, so the initial $S$ was not a solution.

Comment: @MarzioDeBiasi, well, 2!=1 and also 0!=1, so none of {3,4} adjacent to exactly 1 vertex. So, {1,2} is critical.

Comment: @RaduGRIGore: ouch, now I see it :-S

Answer (score 5):

The problem is known as the *propagation problem*. Aazami has proved in his [PhD thesis](http://hdl.handle.net/10012/4147) that the weighted version is NP-complete even when the graph is planar and the node weights are in $\{0,1\}$. The complexity for the unweighted version seems to be an open problem.